# Metamask web3.eth.account[0] is undefined

Tags: metamask

I am facing some problem with metamask.
I ve copied the code below from the metamask documentation to load the web3 but i get always `web3.eth.accounts[0] returns undefined` when i try to get the account's address even if metamask is connected to ropsten. The same code works with Mist perfectly.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        console.log("Metamask used");
    } else {
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
        // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/token"));
    }

    console.log('test1'+web3.eth.accounts[0]);

});
console.log('test'+web3.eth.accounts[0]);
```

i get the output of the first log.

Comment: this is your code? maybe is a problem of the asynchronous system... Are you using well the callback function :/ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Metamask does not let you use synchronous functions. Use instead:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    ...
});
```

And remove your second log. You only want to do things after you have properly initialised.

Comment: Thank you but i think it is a loading issue, because after some refresh it returns the address.

Comment: don't go first error and not accounts? :/ web3.eth.getBlock(48, function(error, result){
    if(!error)
        console.log(result)
    else
        console.error(error);
})

Comment: Fixed `error, accounts`.

Comment: If after some refresh it works, it is more likely that it works by a quirk of the refresh. It should work at the first go.

Comment: @Etherkimist try to define before the Web3 constant o check the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use await for synchronization.

```
const getAccount = async () => {
  ...
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const account = accounts[0];
  return account;
}
```